# string in binary format to integer

Tags: c

i am trying to convert a string containing a 16-bit number in binary to a integer value.
It is a homework assignment and i have to use scanf("%1d.... ).
The problem i am having is that the loop wont end, i have no clue how to fix it.

for example:
input: 0000000000001111
output: 15

```
int read_binary_value()
{ 
int value = 0;

while( scanf("%1d", &value) == 1) 
{
    printf("%d ", value);
    if (value == 1)
    {
        value += 1;
        value << 1;
    }

 }
 printf("yoyoyoyoyoyoyo");
 printf("%d",value);

 return value;
}
```

Comment: your while expression probably returns when you are ending it.  Check if there is another way to express it.

Comment: it doesnt get to the "yoyoyoyoy" part when i compile it, i dont understand that

Comment: a while loop loops until the condition is false, otherwise it will run forever.  In your case, it will scan forever.

Comment: You need to decide on what condition to use to indicate that the input has completed. For example, you could use the assumption that all 16 bits need to be entered. Then just use a `for` loop with 16 iterations instead of the current `while` loop. Then the loop completes when all 16 digits have been read or an invalid character is encountered.

Comment: Note that, if this is not a programming exercise / homework assignment, a call to [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) would be preferable.

Comment: Also, note that `value << 1;` doesn't change the `value` variable. You need to do `value <<= 1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code and it works

```
int read_binary_value()
{
    int total=0;
    int value;
    while( scanf("%1d", &value) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d", value);
        if(!(value==0||value==1))
        {
            //Generate Error Message and Exit program
        }
        total = total << 1;
        if (value == 1)
        {
            total += 1;
        }

    }
    printf("yoyoyoyoyoyoyo\n");
    printf("%d",total);
    return total;
}
```

Your loop stop when get end of file.
Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for windows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for linux.  Those are End of File character.

Comment: thanks a lot!  are there options to avoid pressing CTRL+Z ?

Comment: With scanf() in this condition, I don't know. You can read as string then convert it to integer.

Comment: It is insane to require the use of `scanf("%1d")` in the first place.  Using getchar() would make so much more sense.  `scanf` and friends are almost never the correct solution to any parsing problem.

Comment: The problem with `scanf` is that you cannot detect spaces to separate binary numbers.  `1 1` will be converted to `3` just like `11` or even `1\n1`, hardly expected behaviour!

Comment: Also, you should check if `value` is different from `0` and `1`:  parsing `121` as `5` would be incorrect.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Thanks to this extra test, you can simplify the code and remove the second test: `total += total + value;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 16 inputs you can use
`for(i=0;i<16;i++)` instead of the `while` to just run the loop 16 times and end. Or else within the `while` loop you can give 
`if(i==16) 
break;` incrementing `i` at the end of the loop. If you need to manually stop the loop, `EOF` char is the option.